# SwiftUI widget onReceive method to getTimeline Func

Tags: swift, swiftui, widget

```
//
//  AuthWidget.swift
//  AuthWidget
//
//  Created by Sametcan on 29.10.2023.
//

import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import SwiftOTP
import GAuthSwiftParser
import SwiftOTP
import Combine

struct Provider: TimelineProvider {
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        SimpleEntry(date: .now, names: [], icons: [], keys: [], services: [])
    }

    func getSnapshot(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
        let data = fetchDataFromCoreData()

        let names = data.compactMap { $0.name ?? "" }
        let icons = data.compactMap { $0.icon ?? "" }
        let keys = data.compactMap { $0.key ?? "" }
        let services = data.compactMap { $0.service ?? "" }

        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: .now, names: names, icons: icons, keys: keys, services: services)
        completion(entry)
    }


    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []

        let data = fetchDataFromCoreData() // Core Data'dan verileri çek

        let names = data.compactMap { $0.name ?? "" }
        let icons = data.compactMap { $0.icon ?? "" }
        let keys = data.compactMap { $0.key ?? "" }
        let services = data.compactMap { $0.service ?? "" }
        let currentDate = Date()

        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: currentDate, names: names, icons: icons, keys: keys, services: services)
        entries.append(entry)

        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
    }
}

struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let names: [String]
    let icons: [String]
    let keys: [String]
    let services: [String]

}


struct AuthWidgetEntryView: View {
    @State var progress: Float = 0.0
    @State var secondsUntilRefresh = 0
    @State private var codes: [String] = []
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    @State var timeInterval = 30

    var entry: Provider.Entry
    var symbols = ["AdobeIllustrator", "AdobePhotoshop", "AdobeXD", "Aim", "Airbnb", "Airtable", "Amazon", "Android"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0..<min(3, entry.names.count), id: \.self) { index in
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                    .fill(Color("buttonBG"))
                    .overlay {
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            if symbols.contains(entry.services[index]) {
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 100).fill(Color("WidgetBackground")).frame(width: 50, height: 50).overlay {
                                    Image(entry.services[index])
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                                        .cornerRadius(100)
                                }
                            } else {
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 100).fill(Color("WidgetBackground")).frame(width: 50, height: 50).overlay {
                                    Image("defaultIcon")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                                        .cornerRadius(100)
                                }
                            }

                            VStack {
                                Text(entry.services[index])
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                    .font(.system(size: 18))
                                    .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                                    .lineLimit(1)
                                    .bold()
                                
                                Text(entry.names[index])
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                    .font(.system(size: 13))
                                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                            }.foregroundStyle(.white)

                            Spacer()
                            CircularProgressBar(progress: $progress,
                                color: secondsUntilRefresh <= 5 ? .constant(.red) : .constant(.accentColor))
                                .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
                        }.padding(.init(top: 10, leading: 16, bottom: 1, trailing: 16))

                        HStack(spacing:10) {
                            if codes.indices.contains(index) {
                                let code = codes[index] // Use the codes array, not entry.keys
                                let codeCharacters = code.map { String($0) }

                                ForEach(codeCharacters.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                                        .fill(Color("WidgetBackground"))
                                        .frame(width: 35, height: 35).overlay {
                                        Text(codeCharacters[index])
                                            .foregroundStyle(.white)
                                            .font(.system(size: 18))
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                Text("")
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(.bottom)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
            .font(.system(size: 10))
            .onAppear {
            updateCodes()
            secondsUntilRefresh = calculateSecondsUntilRefresh()
            progress = 1 - Float(secondsUntilRefresh) / Float(timeInterval)
        }
            .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                updateCodes()
                let remainder = calculateSecondsUntilRefresh()
                secondsUntilRefresh = remainder
                progress = 1 - Float(secondsUntilRefresh) / Float(timeInterval)
            }
    
    }
    func generateSixDigitCode(from key: String) -> String? {
        guard let secretData = base32DecodeToData(key),
            let totp = TOTP(secret: secretData, digits: 6, timeInterval: timeInterval) else {
            print("Error decoding secret key or creating TOTP")
            return "000000"
        }
        return totp.generate(time: .now)
    }
    func updateCodes() {
        codes = entry.keys.compactMap { generateSixDigitCode(from: $0) }
    }
    func calculateSecondsUntilRefresh() -> Int {
        return timeInterval - Int(floor(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)) % timeInterval
    }
}

struct myWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "AuthWidget"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
                AuthWidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
                    .containerBackground(Color("WidgetBackground"), for: .widget)
                
            } else {
                AuthWidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
                    .padding()
                    .background()
            }
        }
        
        .supportedFamilies([.systemSmall,.systemMedium,.systemLarge])
        
            .configurationDisplayName("My Widget")
            .description("This is an example widget.")
    }
}


struct CircularProgressBar: View {
    @Binding var progress: Float
    @Binding var color: Color

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .stroke(lineWidth: 6)
                .opacity(0.3)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)

            Circle()
                .trim(from: 0.0, to: CGFloat(min(max(0.01, progress), 1.0)))
                .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 6, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                .foregroundColor(color)
                .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 270))
                .animation(.linear,value: progress)
        }
    }
}
//#Preview(as: .systemSmall) {
//    myWidget()
//} timeline: {
//    SimpleEntry(date: .now, name: "")
//    SimpleEntry(date: .now, name: "")
//}
```

By performing the operations I do in the "getTimeline" function and easily displaying them as an Authenticator widget, I believe that with each operation, time will decrease, and new passwords, service token keys, and names will be generated automatically. Since I cannot use the "onReceive" method, I have to use this function. This way, I can automate my processes and save time, generating new passwords, service token keys, and names.

Comment: A widget is like a GIF, all properties should be “let”.